# Python - Descriptor 'split' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'

Tags: python

Erm, I have ready-to-use code, and I'm sure it really works, but I get the following error:

> TypeError: descriptor 'split' requires a 'str' object but received a
>   'unicode'

That's the whole def:

```
def assemblePacket(self, type):
    ipSplit = str.split(self.serverVars[0], '.')

    packet = 'SAMP'
    packet += chr(int(ipSplit[0]))
    packet += chr(int(ipSplit[1]))
    packet += chr(int(ipSplit[2]))
    packet += chr(int(ipSplit[3]))
    packet += chr(self.serverVars[1] & 0xFF)
    packet += chr(self.serverVars[1] >> 8 & 0xFF)
    packet += type

    return packet
```

And here is the problem:

```
ipSplit = str.split(self.serverVars[0], '.')
```

I'm sure it's not because of the code, I've tried it before (the same script) and it worked. No idea why it doesn't now.And this "unicode" makes me think I have to change "str.split", but hmmm. Waiting for opinions :)

Comment: "I'm sure it really works, but I get the following error".. umn, so you're actually sure it doesn't work, because well, it really doesn't?

Comment: You might consider using the `struct` module instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that `str.split` is a method of the `str` class, but is being called for an object of the `unicode` class. Call the method directly with `ipSplit = self.serverVars[0].split('.')` to have it work for anything (including `str` and `unicode`) with a `split` method.

Comment: I don't see why this is a problem. When I run this code, it work fine: >>>u'a.b'.split('.')  ===> The result is:             
[u'a', u'b']

Comment: @DavidMorton Yes, the code you posted should work fine. The problem is with `str.split(u'a.b', '.')`.

Answer (score 15):

As @Abe mentioned, the problem here is, you are using [str.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split an object of type `unicode` which is causing the failure.

There are three options for you

1. In this particular case, you can simply call the `split()` method for the object. This will ensure that irrespective of the type of the object (`str`, `unicode`), the method call would handle it properly.
2. You can also call `unicode.split()`. This will work well for `unicode` string but for `non-unicode` string, this will fail again.
3. Finally, you can import the [string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#module-string) module and call the [string.split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) function. This function converts the `split()` function call to method call thus enabling you to transparently call the `split()` irrespective if the object type. This is beneficial when you are using the `split()` as callbacks esp to functions like `map()`

Comment: Yeah, it worked with the first option, I called the method. Thank you anyways!

Comment: Third option was useful for me. I tend to use quite some functional programming style. One more reason to use the string module despite pylint warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Neither method worked when using `isdigit`. If you are in a similar solution, you could try a `try`-`except` block similar to

```
try:
    output += filter(str.isdigit, some_string)
except TypeError:
    output += filter(unicode.isdigit, some_string)
```